# Apache CXF Swagger UI JSON file does not show anything

Tags: apache, jax-rs, cxf, swagger, swagger-ui

I am adding swagger in my Rest Web Service (Apache CXF and Spring). However, when I try to navigate in my swagger url for json, nothing happens, nothing is displayed. Below is my configuration files.

-CXF version 3.1.6
-SwaggerFeature2

When navigation to this URL http://localhost:9080/api/swagger.json

> Error: No operation matching request path "/api/swagger" is found

Tried to read other posts here but none has worked. Please give me some light. Thanks.

```
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="validationInInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>

    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
        <ref bean="exceptionMapper" />
    </jaxrs:providers>

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="myWebServiceRs" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:features>
        <ref bean="swagger2Feature" />
    </jaxrs:features>

    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>


<bean id="jsonProvider"
    class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
```

This is swagger-ui.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/3.0.3" mapping="/api/**" />


    <bean id="swagger2Feature" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger.Swagger2Feature" >
```

index.html

```
    window.onload = function() {

    alert("entry!");
  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "/api/swagger.json",
    validatorUrl : null,
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      // yay ES6 modules ↘
      Array.isArray(SwaggerUIStandalonePreset) ? SwaggerUIStandalonePreset : SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.default
    ],
```

Comment: Can you share an executable project? You can find working samples here: https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs

Comment: Please also note that latest CXF version is 3.2.6, you should upgrade to get the latest fixes.

Comment: My sample dummy is here [link](https://github.com/ElishevaSales/Studies/tree/master/OlaSample). I changed the version of cxf I used. I am using CXF 3.1.10 and it the documentation it says that the Swagger UI is already automated when you open in the browser http://localhost:9080/context/service/api-docs/url?=/context/swagger.json. But sadly no UI is being displayed. :(

Comment: Hi I was able to resolve my issue. I just added a new servlet of Spring that access the resource of swagger-ui folder to show the swagger-ui page. I do not know what exactly was the culprit. But I am happy now that I made it work. Thank you. :)